# Get() not working propely

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

i have a code where i need to read a csv and save on my database , but, fot read they need to convert to a collection ,the method "->get()" should do it , but is not,PhpStorm is saying **the method is not found in void ** ,so ... i dont have more ideias ,i apreciate if someone could help me , i put the cde bellow

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{
    dump("passo 1");
    if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
        dump("passo 2");
        $file=Excel::load($request->file('import_file')->getRealPath(),function($reader){ })->get();
        dd($file);
        dd("fim");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data in the closer passing variable in the function and you can do either

```
$reader->get();
```

or

```
$reader->all();
```

or you can loop the data and save it in ur model

```
Excel::load($request->file('import_file'), function ($reader) {

  foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {
     User::firstOrCreate($row);
  }
});
```

if you need the variable outside the scope add & before the variable.

```
function(&$reader) {}
```

Comment: Thnaks man , but not work =( , i try what you say , ( i put the code below ) but ... PhpStorm stay saying "method XXX not found in less... Reference method is not found in subject class." Do you have any Ideia ?

Comment: Phpstrom can't read facades , you have to check in the browser or create a test for that function